# Unable to launch sqlite3 in my sumsung phone

Tags: sqlite

I have put the libncurses.so and sqlite3 in the /xbin , but it seems unable to  load the library "libncurse.so". waiting for help !
[image]

Comment: What is your source of sqlite3? I also have sqlite3 but it doesn't require that .so file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of libncurses.so is wrong.

It should be: /system/lib/libncurses.so

Comment: Thx for your advice，I will take a try when I return home.

Comment: I've try to put it in /bin but it doesn't work. How bothersome. I have no other way but using log in Android Studio to query my database.

Comment: no, not in /bin, but in /system/lib/. Are you sure that your libncurses.so is compiled for ARM arch?

Comment: Oh Jesus! I've mistaken it for bin. 